# How to implement cruiseControl in flex project Building

Tags: apache-flex, cruisecontrol

I need to deploy my project automatically using cruise Control .Please give a example

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try using the cruise control binary distribution found here - http://sourceforge.net/projects/cruisecontrol/files/CruiseControl/2.8.4/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4.zip/download
2. Automating your flex project build using ant will be a lot easier with flexAnt. You will find the jar in a location similar to C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4\sdks\4.0.0\ant\lib where C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4 is the installation path for Adobe Flash Builder.
3. Giving you an outright example is difficult, but you can start with a very thorough guide like http://www.unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2010/01/07/using-ant-to-build-an-application/. This is only a single post and Jonathan has many more articles on how to automate builds for libraries, for air projects etc. Just search through the site and chances are that you will find what you are looking for. If that does not work, you always have StackOverflow! :D

Regards,
Ravi.